# How To Refresh GridlookupEdit datasource with another datasource

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

here I will explain what I want to ask.
before I explain what is my problem.

I created a program and I add 1 forms, in my form I add combobox and components of deexpress is GridLookupEdit.

the function of the **combobox** itself which displays options category.

while **Gridlookup** will display data from the database based on the category selected from Combobox.

At the time I chose the first category, namely 'Study Program' from the combobox, then the data is successfully performing in GridLookup.

**But** When I choose a category of the Other, which is the data based Category I choose the existing data in the database, but it can not show all GridLookup.

And Gridlookup only list items that previously emptied and menyisahkan Name column of the previous data.

for code that I use and I Attach screenshot on the following page:

```
    Private Sub CBCariOpt_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CBCariOpt.SelectedIndexChanged
    With CBCariOpt
        If .SelectedIndex = -1 Or .Text = "" Then Exit Sub
        If .SelectedIndex = 0 Or .SelectedIndex = 1 Or .SelectedIndex = 4 Or .SelectedIndex = 5 Then
           GLOptCari.Properties.DataSource = DBNull.Value
           FilDataBantuGridLookup(.SelectedIndex, GLOptCari, DKritria, General.Constant.ConfigPath)
        Else
           GLOptCari.SendToBack()
           With DKritria
                    .BringToFront()
                    .Text = ""
                    .Focus()
                    .Select()
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Code For FillData into Data source Gridlookup

```
   Private Sub FilDataBantuGridLookup(SelIndex As Integer, GL As GridLookUpEdit, dkritria As MetroTextBox, path As String)
    With QD
       If SelIndex = 0 Then .FillToGridLook(QProdi, GL, "PRODI", "KODE", path)
       If SelIndex = 1 Then .FillToGridLook(QJursan, GL, "JURUSAN", "KODE", path)
       If SelIndex = 4 Then .FillToGridLook(QThAnktan, GL, "THN_ANGKATAN", "THN_ANGKATAN", path)
       If SelIndex = 5 Then .FillToGridLook(QThWisda, GL, "THN_WISUDA", "THN_WISUDA", path)
       .Dispose()
       GL.Properties.PopupFormSize = New Size With {.Width = GL.Width} 'GridLookUpEdit
       GL.BringToFront()
       dkritria.SendToBack()
    End With
End Sub
```

Query To DataSource In GridLookupEdit :

```
Public Sub FillToGridLook(ByVal query As String, FilCtl As DevExpress.XtraEditors.GridLookUpEdit, SDis As String, SVal As String, ByVal path As String)
    Using KN As New Koneksi.Koneksi
        If KN.OpenFromFile(path) Then
            Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, KN.OKoneksi)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt = New DataTable
                dt.Rows.Clear()
                dt.Columns.Clear()
                da.Fill(dt)
                If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    FilCtl.Refresh()
                    FilCtl.RefreshEditValue()
                    With FilCtl.Properties
                        .DataSource = Nothing
                        .DataSource = dt
                        .DisplayMember = SDis
                        .ValueMember = SVal
                        .ImmediatePopup = True
                        .View.OptionsView.ShowColumnHeaders = False
                    End With
                    FilCtl.Refresh()

                End If
                da.Dispose()
                dt.Dispose()
            End Using
        End If
        KN.Dispose()
    End Using
End Sub
```

For Result :

[Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG1Mq.jpg)

therefore, I would like to ask,:

1. **How to refresh the DataSource in gridlookup who initially had to accommodate the initial data prior to the new data?**

Comment: you must put these image and sample project in shared folder rather than private.. your statements are little ambiguous so please explain it in clearly ..

Comment: i've repost my code and Result Xample...

Please Help me..

Theank's..

Comment: why are you disposing lookupedit data source?? you should not dispose data source of the control.. do not dispose dt..

Comment: If i didn't dispose, result it same like ScreenShoot.

Comment: Then please put your sample project in shared folder on google drive to test it quickly..or use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com), [ideone](http://ideone.com/)